# how do i get mamp to use localhost socket instead of 0.0.0.0

Tags: php, mysql, apache, sockets

This is a new installation of MAMP for PC.

When I start mamp up, it seems to be setting up sockets for apache and mysql on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost (127.0.0.1).  As a result, when trying to access the site, which is on the localhost, it fails to connect.  The msql_error_log entries show this is true for mysql

```
150726 12:32:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 8889
150726 12:32:27 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
150726 12:32:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
```

and errors are generated by apache showing that when localhost is used apache is looking for files at 127.0.0.1:

```
http://localhost:8888/MAMP/htdocs
[Sun Jul 26 11:44:58 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/MAMP/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 26 11:44:58 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/MAMP/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 26 11:44:59 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/MAMP/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 26 11:44:59 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/MAMP/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 26 11:45:31 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/MAMP/htdocs/docs-assets, referer:
```

I'm using the default ports 8888 and 8889, and netstat -a shows that the sockets using these ports are on 0.0.0.0.

When I open the MAMP start page (localhost:8888/MAMP/) on my browser it opens just fine, but when I try to connect to the site at localhost:8888/MAMP/htdocs/, I get the 404 error.

Has anyone seen this problem or know of a solution to it?

Comment: When netstat shows a server listening on 0.0.0.0, that means it's listening on that port on all IP addresses. In this case it's listening both on 127.0.0.1 and on your machine's IP address (probably assigned by DHCP).

Comment: What happens when your browser hits `http://localhost:8888/` ? That's the URL corresponding to the directory 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\'  in your file system.

Comment: Thank  you for responding to my question.  

When I browse to http://localhost:8888/, I get the data base error message: "Error establishing a database connection".